# Core Data in Xcode 8, regarding to create NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8

I am using Core Data for my data storage at the moment.

When I generate the `NSManagedObject`, in the header file, there are two types of files are generated.

For example, I have an entity as 'Location', the the NSManagedObject was generated as:

> Location+CoreDataClass.h

and

> Location+CoreDataProperties.h

Which is quite confused, what does it mean? And in my project, when I import the file in other classes, what am I supposed to import?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is than before, if you create custom methods in MyObject.h and then regenerate the NSMAnagedObject, all your stuff was lost.

So Now, only the `Location+CoreDataProperties.h` will be override. So put all your stuff in `Location+CoreDataClass.h`. If you add a new attribute, only the Properties.h will be updated

Comment: But, before when we generate the core data NSManagedObject, which is just the 'Location.h', so what is the difference between 'Location.h' and 'Location+CoreDataClass.h'

Comment: Xcode just split properties and methods in two separate files to avoid losing data and new generation

Comment: Thanks it makes a lot sense.